# Unable to utilise Propel's validation (please, define the validator constraint)

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I'm currently using Propel with my own framework and I'm trying to implement the validation model with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="framework" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table name="page" phpName="Page">
        <!-- Columns -->
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
        <column name="description" type="varchar" size="255" required="false" />
        <column name="keywords" type="varchar" size="255" required="false" />
        <column name="content" type="longvarchar" required="false" />
        <column name="template_id" type="integer" required="false" />
        <column name="publish_date" type="date" required="false" />
        <!-- Validators -->
        <behavior name="validate">
            <parameter name="rule1" value="{column: title, validator: NotNull}" />
        </behavior>
        <!-- Behaviors -->
        <behavior name="i18n">
            <parameter name="i18n_columns" value="title, description, content" />
            <parameter name="default_locale" value="en_GB" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="nested_set" />
        <behavior name="sluggable" />
        <behavior name="sortable" />
        <behavior name="timestampable" />
        <!-- Foreign Keys -->
        <foreign-key foreignTable="page_template">
            <reference local="template_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>
</database>
```

When running `model:build` against the above schema, notably with the following nodes included:

```
<!-- Validators -->
<behavior name="validate">
    <parameter name="rule1" value="{column: title, validator: NotNull}" />
</behavior>
```

It returns with:

```
[Propel\Generator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
Please, define the validator constraint.
```

However as you can see, the validator property is set.

If I remove the validate behavior, it works fine.

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Cheers

Gav

Comment: It seems it's related to when you try validating a column that's handled by i18n...